# Random Apps Crash at Different Times after Running an Application I've Developed

Tags: java, android, multithreading, performance

I have developed an android application which contains multiple threads and processes. The application itself works great however I keep getting dialog messages telling me that 'Unfortunately (some random app) has stopped'. Sometimes I'll get a message when I start my app, sometimes not until I close my app and sometimes I won't get a message like this at all. The following are just some of the apps I've seen crash while/after running mine: Weather, Clock, Settings, WiFi & many more. The randomness of this issue has made it difficult to pinpoint the cause.

Things I have tried:

- Clearing the cache of my app and all other apps.
- Rebooting the device.
- Uninstalling/Reinstalling my app.

Any suggestions are appreciated?

Comment: post your logcat here

Comment: Note the logcat at the time of crash and post it here

Comment: Guys, its not his app thats crashing. How can he get logcat from release builds of (some random app)? I think this question is better suited for http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot post the log cat but I've looked at it and I'm not seeing any exceptions while running my app and after closing my app when I started getting dialog messages that apps have stopped. I am leaning towards maybe it is more of a memory issue since my app behaves fine but forces other apps to crash.

Comment: I'll try android stack exchange

Comment: Do a step by step error debugging

use try n catch and catch exception revolve the cause of this it will take time but make your app more reliable

Comment: @bearbear Try on another device/emulator, if it's specific to your current device, I suspect a memory related issue.